# HTMLService forms and responses

Tags: google-apps-script

New to Google scripts.  I cannot for the life of me get a Google script for forms working.  The documentation is not helpful and I could not find any complete examples.

In sheets, I went to the script section.  I created a basic "hello world" html.  I added a function useMyForm, that will call on the script that has the form in it.  After submit I cannot get the form to call the other script that has onFormSubmit.

Can someone write me a form with one entry and a call to the function that will process the data?  Maybe my functions shouldn't be in separate scripts.

I write c, php, java..... this google script stuff is killing me.

Comment: An HTML form, and a Google Form are two different things.  HTML can be used in a stand alone app, a dialog box, or a sidebar.  It's always the initial "no brainer" stuff that takes me forever to learn.  Take a look at my Profile and send me an email if you want.

Comment: I understand that.  I just want my google form to communicate with my scripts.  Do you know someone who actually knows how to write that?  I'm in the script editor and created an html file that will host my form.

Comment: Did you create your own html form, or are you trying to use the product Google Forms?

Comment: I think you are looking for: google.script.run.yourfunction(variable);

Comment: In google sheets you can click on tools->scripts.  Then you have the option of writing a .gs file and .html...... I want to write a script for a form that will be embedded in the .html.... I need to see sample code for both to see how to set it up.  I've been looking for hours and there is no sample code that is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the sample code from the documentation, if there is something you don't understand please post your own version of the code that is not working:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#forms

Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
}

function processForm(formObject) {
  var formBlob = formObject.myFile;
  var driveFile = DriveApp.createFile(formBlob);
  return driveFile.getUrl();
}
```

index.html

```
<script>
  function updateUrl(url) {
    var div = document.getElementById('output');
    div.innerHTML = '<a href="' + url + '">Got it!</a>';
  }
</script>
<form id="myForm">
  <input name="myFile" type="file" />
  <input type="button" value="Submit"
      onclick="google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(updateUrl)
          .processForm(this.parentNode)" />
</form>
<div id="output"></div>
```

The one thing that took me a while to grasp is that when you run `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateUrl).processForm(this.parentNode)`

`.processForm(variable)` will run a function in the .gs file.
The return from that function (in the .gs file) gets sent to the `.withSuccessHandler(updateUrl)` function.  Which in the example above is the "url" variable from `function updateUrl(url)`

Comment: Thanks so much.  All of my code worked... I needed to authenticate two functions.  This is a google script "thing" I've never come across before.

Comment: The only way that the .html file talks to the .gs file is through google.script.run.   Or you can open the html in template mode (see documentation) which will allow you to insert .gs code into the html code.